# “does not name a type” error c++

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors

I have a class declared as below, and I keep getting "Segment does not name a type" error. I've looked at other similar questions but I can't seem to find a solution to my problem. Any help? Thanks in advance! :)

```
#ifndef ENTRANCE_H
#define ENTRANCE_H
#include "Segment.h"
#include <vector>
#include "Diodio.h"


class Entrance
{
    public:
        Entrance();
        ~Entrance();
        void operate();


    protected:
        Segment *givesEntryTo;
        std::vector<Diodio> elBooths;
            std::vector<Diodio> manBooths;

    private:
};

#endif // ENTRANCE_H
```

Comment: Most likely you have a circular dependency between your headers.

Comment: A guess: does Segment.h directly or indirectly include Entrance.h?

Comment: This is a class **definition**. A class declaration would be `class Entrance;`.

Comment: @molbdnilo I'll look into that thanks for the suggestion

Comment: @DimChtz Segment is a class that represents a segment of a highway and for the entrance i need a pointer that points to what segment the entrance gives entry to.

Comment: @IInspectable yes it does because entrance needs to use stuff from Segment and segment needs to use stuff from Entrance. This is my first project so there might be some obvious mistake that I have done.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can avoid a circular include problem by using a *forward declaration* of a class instead of an `#include`:

```
#ifndef ENTRANCE_H
#define ENTRANCE_H
#include <vector>
#include "Diodio.h"

class Segment;    

class Entrance
{
    public:
        Entrance();
        ~Entrance();
        void operate();


    protected:
        Segment *givesEntryTo;
        std::vector<Diodio> elBooths;
            std::vector<Diodio> manBooths;

    private:
};

#endif // ENTRANCE_H
```

(Entrance.cpp may or may not need to `#include "Segment.H"` then.)